# How to unselect an image from Image Picker in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui, uiimagepickercontroller

I am creating a message app with SwiftUI.

I have made an Image Picker to allow sending photos.

Here is the code of my Image Picker :

```
import SwiftUI

struct ImagePicker: UIViewControllerRepresentable {

    @Binding var image: UIImage?
    
    @Binding var didSet: Bool

    private let controller = UIImagePickerController()
    
    var sourceType: UIImagePickerController.SourceType = .photoLibrary

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(parent: self)
    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

        let parent: ImagePicker

        init(parent: ImagePicker) {
            self.parent = parent
        }

        func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
            parent.image = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage
            parent.didSet = true
            picker.dismiss(animated: true)
        }

        func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
            picker.dismiss(animated: true)
        }

    }

    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> some UIViewController {
        controller.sourceType = sourceType
        controller.allowsEditing = false
        controller.delegate = context.coordinator

        return controller
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewControllerType, context: Context) {

    }

}
```

When a picture is selected, it is shown in a view, so that, the user can see it before sending it.

I would like to implement a button that would unselect the image shown, but I don't know how to do it. I would like to know if there is a way to unselect the image.

Do you have any ideas ?

Thank you.

Comment: You should be able to simply set the your Image variable to nil. Have you tried that? ☺️

Comment: @JamesWilliam Yes, I tried, but I can't assign nil to a UIImage type

Comment: Strange, pretty sure you should be able to set an optional UIImage var to nil... what about if you assign it an empty UIImage()?

Comment: Actually, assigning nil worked. I couldn't set it before because I used an if let to declare my image, so I changed with self. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Oh great! Glad I am able to help! ☺️